# Trying to find palindrome years, I'm reversing and cutting an int in half, but only the first half would fill

Tags: c, concatenation, palindrome

See the following code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int isPalindromePossible(int);
unsigned concatenate(unsigned, unsigned);
int jour, mois, annee, jm, length, leng, begin, end;
char str[12], str2[12], revstr[40];

int main() {
    printf("Entrez le jour : ");
    scanf("%d", &jour);
    printf("Entrez le mois : ");
    scanf("%d", &mois);
    printf("Entrez l'annee : ");
    scanf("%d", &annee);

    int test = reverse(annee);
    isPalindromePossible(annee);
    
    return 0;
}

int isPalindromePossible(int year) {
    int firstHalf;
    int secondHalf;
    
    while (year > 0) {
        int digit = year % 10;
        printf("YEAR = %d\n", year);
        if (year <= 99) {
            concatenate(secondHalf, digit);
        } else {
            concatenate(firstHalf, digit);
        }
        year = year / 10;
    }
    
    printf("FH = %d, SH = %d", firstHalf, secondHalf);
    
    return 0;
}

unsigned concatenate(unsigned x, unsigned y) {
    unsigned pow = 10;
    while(y >= pow)
        pow *= 10;
    return x * pow + y;        
}
```

[The code was ran, and output this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/flTof.png)

See how the second half never gets filled, even tho the if statement is working. I'm scratching my head and can't figure out why.

If you see the problem I'd appreciate.

Many thanks.

Comment: dont post images instead post as text

Comment: I'll be sure to do that next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of `firstHalf` and `secondHalf` are used without being initialized. You invoked *undefined behavior* by using values of uninitialized non-static local variables, which are indeterminate.

You have to

- Initialize them to zero.
- Update them to return values of `concatenate`.

```
int isPalindromePossible(int year) {
    int firstHalf = 0;
    int secondHalf = 0;
    
    while (year > 0) {
        int digit = year % 10;
        printf("YEAR = %d\n", year);
        if (year <= 99) {
            secondHalf = concatenate(secondHalf, digit);
        } else {
            firstHalf = concatenate(firstHalf, digit);
        }
        year = year / 10;
    }
    
    printf("FH = %d, SH = %d", firstHalf, secondHalf);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, stupid error from my side, forgot to update the values.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution (removing the procedure of concatenate):

```
int isPalindromePossible(int year) {
int firstHalf = 0;//initialize at 0
int secondHalf = 0;//initialize at 0

int l =(int)log10((double)year)+1;//calculate the number of digits of year
int s=0;

// while loop for finding the mirror of year
while (year > 0)
{
    int digit = year % 10;
    s=s*10+digit;
    printf("\n%d\n",year);
    year = year / 10;
}
 
 firstHalf=s%(int)round (pow(10,(double)l/2));//first part of number
 secondHalf=s/(int)round (pow(10,(double)l/2));//Second part of number

 printf("\nFH = %d, SH = %d", firstHalf, secondHalf);

return 0;

}
```